# числа с плавающей точкой PHP

Tags: php, числа, float

Поделитесь опытом как сравнивать/обрабатывать такие числа.

У меня на практике встретилась такая ситуация: нужно сравнить числа из базы `350` и число полученное парсером `350,00`,  `120.5` и `120,50` как их сравнивать и приводить к единому формату?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Php сам разберётся с числами в строках. Надо только заменить запятую на точку:

http://ideone.com/Vt46xG

```
<?php

$a = 350;
$b = '350,00';
$c = '120.5';
$d = '120,50';

$b = str_replace(',', '.', $b);
$c = str_replace(',', '.', $c);
$d = str_replace(',', '.', $d);

echo ($a == $b ? "$a == $b\n" : "$a != $b\n");
echo ($c == $d ? "$c == $d\n" : "$c != $d\n");
echo ($a == $c ? "$a == $c\n" : "$a != $c\n");
```

Вывод:

```
350 == 350.00
120.5 == 120.50
350 != 120.5
```

Answer (score 0):

Методом привидения к типу (float):

```
    <?php
    $a = 350;
    $b = '350,00';
    $c = '120.5';
    $d = '120,50';

    echo "Результаты сравнения: a и b: ";
    echo ((float)$a == (float)$b)?"равны":"не равны";
    echo '<br>'.PHP_EOL;

    echo "Результаты сравнения: a и c: ";
    echo ((float)$a > (float)$c)?"больше":"меньше";
    echo '<br>'.PHP_EOL;

    echo "Результаты сравнения: a и d: ";
    echo ((float)$a < (float)$d)?"меньше":"больше";
    echo '<br>'.PHP_EOL;
?>
```

[Где почитать](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.types.type-juggling.php)

Результат выполнения:

```
Результаты сравнения: a и b: равны
Результаты сравнения: a и c: больше
Результаты сравнения: a и d: больше
```

Если сделать gettype(), то покажет, что тип (double).

Comment: Неверно. http://ideone.com/Rzf3YY - `Результаты сравнения: c и d: не равны`